# Kornshell - How to print up to a certain string in a file

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, ksh

Say there is a file with some text in it, and say we're looking for a certain string inside that text.  How would you go about printing the contents of that file up until the first instance of that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/\(pattern\).*/{s//\1/; q;}'
```

Comment: Would the reverse of this be: sed '/{s//\1/; q;}.*'/\(pattern\)' ?

Answer (score 1):

Use sed with `q` command:

```
sed '/pattern/q' file
```

This will print file until `pattern` is found and then it will quit rest of the processing.

Comment: If the pattern is in the middle of a line, this command still prints out the rest of the line.  Is there a way to stop the process exactly once the string is found?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of doing it. You can for example use grep's `-n` option to make it output line numbers, extract the first line number and use it to instruct `head` to display a given number of lines out of the file:

```
head -n $(grep -n somestring file | cut -d: -f1 | head -n 1) file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk '!f; /pattern/ {f=1}' file
```

Print line if `f=0`, if `pattern` found set `f=1`

Comment: I'd use `awk '1; /pattern/{exit}' file` instead of that command. IMHO it's simpler and clearer, plus it's definitely more efficient.

Comment: Another even shorter version.  `awk '/search/{exit}1' file`

Comment: That's not the same functionality though as it wouldn't print the line containing the matching string.